# Downloading swimtimes using python

Tags: python, robobrowser

I'm trying to automatically download the swimtimes of lots of swimmers from http://www.usaswimming.org/DesktopDefault.aspx?TabId=1470&Alias=Rainbow&Lang=en-US.

One example of a swimmer would be a swimmer that goes by the last name "Rule" and first name "Remedy". (Yes, there's really such a swimmer!) If you fill in those two fields in the website and click search, it works.

However, although the following code runs without error, it doesn't give me any swimming results at the end:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser()
browser.open("http://www.usaswimming.org/DesktopDefault.aspx?TabId=1470&Alias=Rainbow&Lang=en-US")
form = browser.get_form(id="form1")
form["ctl00$ctl68$txtSearchLastName"].value = "rule"
form["ctl00$ctl68$txtSearchFirstName"].value = "remedy"
browser.submit_form(form)
print(browser.parsed)
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvotes and off-topic close vote?

Comment: The close reason is listed as: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  But it looks to me like you have provided all of the required elements.

Comment: I have just run this code on python `2.7` and `3.5` using robobrowser `0.5.3`, and the `print` disgorged quite a lot of text.

Comment: I just clarified my question to say that even though the code runs without error, it doesn't display any swimming results.

Comment: For example, when I do a search in Chrome, it gives her results at the Texas Hall of Fame.

Comment: So, using the network tab in the chrome 'developer tools', there are quite a few more fields filled out when submitting this form, than the couple of fields you have shown in your exmpale.  Suggest you try to match that.  I also used Wireshark to see what was actually sent, this might also prove useful.  GL.